# The speaker doesnt work unless I use headphone cable

Tags: sound

I installed ubuntu on my pc. I have a problem with the sound. When I want to see videos or anything else, the speaker of the PC doesn't work, but when I use the cable of handsfree/headphones I can hear the voices, which cause another problem when I want to use headphone, the sound also comes from the speaker. I tried a lot of ways, like adding two lines to the sound configuration and changing automate mute to Enabled in alsamixer and ... but this problem happens again and again. And alsamixer also detects HDA Intel PCH as a sound card and also I didn't have sound problems in windows. Should I reinstall Ubuntu again? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. What version/distro of  Ubuntu would be a start...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.